# Using Python to read an audio file that controls animation?

Tags: python

I've done a lot of web searches but I must not be asking the right question -- what I'd like to do is use an audio file to control animation.  Specifically, I want the volume of the file to make the intensity of a material higher (or lower, depending on that volume).  There are other animation programs you can do this in, but I'd love to do it all in Blender and if there is a Python module that can handle this it would be great.

So, IOW, I would load in some .WAV or .MP3 (doesn't matter what I need to use) and the volume would be parsed and as the timeline goes the amount of the diffuse_color_factor would change from 0 to 1 as the volume changes.  Actually, I don't really care if this particular change takes effect -- I just want to return, from the read of that audio file, the volume in some numeric format (which I can then use for whatever purpose I want).

Any clues?

Comment: I would suggest as a starting point use a spectrum analyzer setup similar to GXAudioVisualisation.py and customize for what you want. You can then easily export the F-curve data to a csv file if you just want an absolute numeric reference without loading the audio file again.